# Not starting, just clicking

Tags: starting, diesel, renault, clio

I have a 2002 diesel Renault Clio.

Everything was working fine the day before, but now it will not start. It makes a click noise then nothing. The lights/radio work. Changed the starter motor thinking it could be that but still doesn't start battery has also been charged.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Is it a single click or multiple clicks?